# Sending command to second shell

Tags: shell

Let's say I have one command window open, and it's running some Java application, regularly outputting text.

If I wanted to send a command to it, I could just type it in and press enter.

But how could I automate this? If there's some command to send a command to an open window, then I could put that into a `.sh` with a timer.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to send input to a terminal, right?

Comment: does the window need to remain open?  if not then `screen` can be used. it supports a `-X stuff` option to input to the screen session. i run lots of background stuff that way. *edit*: oh wait, `-X stuff` can input to a screen session that is open/connected.

Comment: @dr01 Yes, in some automated form

Comment: @Skaperen Which window? The original window shoud stay open, yes, the second terminal -- the one accessing it -- I don't care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run things under `screen` to automate stuffing input to applications.  I have scripts in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to make it easier to [start a command in the background](http://skaperen.s3.amazonaws.com/screen-bg) and [stuff input (with control character encoding to let you do things like '\r' or '^c') to any screen sesssion (open or background)](http://skaperen.s3.amazonaws.com/screen-in).

Comment: you don't have to start the application in the background. just run `screen` manually, with the name you choose, in the window you want to see it run in. then in the automation you can run `screen-in` to stuff the input.

Comment: Hi, you edit your answer to include an example of how to do this? Additionally, is the `apt-get` name for screen-in just "scree-in"? Sorry, I'm new to Linux :)